# function call repeating for no apparent reason...Battleship AI malfunction

Tags: c#

I'm a a bit at wits end here... Any help would be greatly appreciated: This code is for the battleship AI competition hosted on this forum, which was then assigned as a project for A.I. class

My problem (aside from being fairly inept at C#) is in the Get Shot function, which seems to call the shot strategy function repeatedly, thus growing the size of my `stratlist`. 
I don't want just a solution to my problem, rather I'd like to understand conceptually why this is happening, and how I can avoid it. Any other style suggestions or hints would also be very welcome. Apologies in advance for any breach of etiquette...this is my first posted question.

On second read this is a bit vague so I'll try to clear it up:

The get shot function declares a Point named shot; it then assigns a value to shot derived by getting a random value (out of 50 values) from the holding list. it the goes on to evaluate this shot in a few ways. Next time we come to the get shot function and get to the second line my list has grown twice in size, and no matter how or where I look I can't figure out why.

Here's the code:

```
namespace Battleship
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Potemkin : IBattleshipOpponent
    {
        public string Name { get { return "Potemkin"; } }
        public Version Version { get { return this.version; } }

        Random rand = new Random();
        Version version = new Version(1, 1);
        Size gameSize;
        bool shotstat = false;
        List<Point> stratlist = new List<Point>();
        List<Point> aimlist = new List<Point>();

        public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
        {
            this.gameSize = size;
            shotstrategy();            
        }

        public void PlaceShips(ReadOnlyCollection<Ship> ships)
        {
            foreach (Ship s in ships)
            {
                s.Place(
                    new Point(
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Width),
                        rand.Next(this.gameSize.Height)),
                    (ShipOrientation)rand.Next(2));
            }
        }

        private void shotstrategy()
        { 
            for (int x = 0; x < gameSize.Width; x++)
                for(int y = 0; y < gameSize.Height; y++)
                    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        stratlist.Add(new Point(x, y));
                    }
        }

        public Point GetShot()
        {
            Point shot;
            shot = this.stratlist[rand.Next(stratlist.Count())];
            if (shotstat == true)
            {
                if (aimlist.Count == 0)
                {
                    fillaimlist(shot);
                }
                while (aimlist.Count > 0)
                {
                    shot = aimlist[0];
                    aimlist.RemoveAt(0);
                    return shot;
                }
            }

            return shot;

        }

        public void NewMatch(string opponent) { }
        public void OpponentShot(Point shot) { }
        public void fillaimlist(Point shot)
        {
            aimlist.Add(new Point(shot.X, shot.Y + 1));
            aimlist.Add(new Point(shot.X, shot.Y - 1));
            aimlist.Add(new Point(shot.X + 1, shot.Y));
            aimlist.Add(new Point(shot.X - 1, shot.Y));        
        }
        public void ShotHit(Point shot, bool sunk)
        {   
            if (!sunk)
            {
                shotstat = true;
            }
            else
            {
                shotstat = false;
            }  
        }
        public void ShotMiss(Point shot) { }
        public void GameWon() { }
        public void GameLost() { }
        public void MatchOver() { }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Do you means that `stratlist` is growing? Where do you call `shotstrategy()`? Maybe it should clear the list first.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `shotstrategy` is not being called somewhere else? Because there seems to be no problem with `GetShot`. The only part of your code that can increase the size of the list is `shotstrategy` function. You need to take closer look to it's calls.

Answer (score 0):

The `GetShot()` function does not seem to increase `stratlist`. Only the `shotstrategy()` functions increases the value.

Your problem is possibly this line

```
stratlist.Add(new Point(x, y));
```

Every time a new game starts you are adding more points. For example, in a 8 by 8 grid, you will have 32 squares as targets.  In the next game; this will add another 32 and so on.

You can work around this, by resetting the `stratlist` value in the `NewGame` function.

```
public void NewGame(Size size, TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    stratlist = new List<Point>
    this.gameSize = size;
    shotstrategy();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time....the problem is still unresolved...I understand that only the shotstrategy() increases the value of my list. The heart of the problem lies at the fact that theoretically my AI should only call that function once per match, at the beggining of the match, when newgame() is called. What happens in reality is that once the code enters getshot() it goes through the function only once and the goes back to newgame(). This makes me realize that my problem is with my understanding of the framework in which this class resides.

Comment: I think I'm just going to go the humble route and ask my professor/classmates to take a peek and point out what I hope is a glaringly small issue. Again thanks for your help and effort, it is much appreciated, hopefully I can pass it on in the future.

Comment: @user2837918 If the purpose of the new game method is to initialise or reset the game; The you should reset all settings in the current game to their starting state.  This includes `startlist`.  If you are having trouble on identifying why this is happening.  Add a break point in the `NewGame()` method as look at the stack trace, identify how the method was invoked and resolve any issues.